# How to set headers in SQLPLUS?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I have set following SQLPLUS commands:

```
SET ECHO OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET HEADING ON
SET LINESIZE 100
SET PAGESIZE 1000
SET SPACE 0
SET TERMOUT OFF
SET TRIMOUT OFF
SET TRIMSPOOL ON
SET VERIFY OFF
```

But i am getting the result as:

```
ERROR_CODE
----------
ERROR_DESC
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR_COUNT
-----------
EXCP098

EXCEPTION: Processing not allowed

          2

EXCP014

EXCEPTION: UNKNOWN STATUS

         11
```

i.e. all the column headings and column values are in a new line instead of all column header should be in the same row and then record 1 should be in the first row and then record 2 should be in the second row.

I want it should be displayed as:

```
ERROR_CODE             ERROR_DESC                          ERROR_COUNT
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
EXCP098             EXCEPTION: Processing not allowed         2

EXCP014             EXCEPTION: UNKNOWN STATUS                11
```

Comment: What's the type (and length) of "ERROR_DESC" and how is it retrieved? (Could it be rather long, and not cut to something short enough to fit on a 100 character wide line (together with "ERROR_CODE" and "ERROR_COUNT").)

Comment: @Abecee: Yes i later tried with using function SUBSTR for the Error_Desc column by keeping it length 40 and my issue got resolved. But is there any other way in which i don't want to mention SUBSTR for any column and i should get the desired output.

Comment: @BobJarvis: I am new to this website, and right now i am facing difficulty in posting the questions as what format i want to post and what's getting posted are having different format. Could you please suggest while posting the question which is the best way, so that the original format should not get changed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just add them. We can edit your post to adjust the formatting.

Comment: [Click this link for help with formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 0):

If "ERROR_DESC" is too long to fit on a line (together with "ERROR_CODE" and "ERROR_COUNT"), you have a few options to try:

- return just a substring,
- `TRIM` the value, or
- change the data type for "ERROR_DESC".

What's working and appropriate, depends on your overall context. After all, the display in SQLPlus is usually not the most important aspect.

Comment: Will do that. Thanks a lot